# android application using listview and gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, baseadapter

I am working on my senior project and I have reached a point where i have an activity with listview that has a radio group in each row and 2 radio buttons in each. And each radio button has a background of a specific picture. The user is supposed to chose 1 radio button from each row. The problem is that i want to get the user's select of the radio button (which is a picture) and send it to another activity that should display all selected pictures in a gridview. I am using a BaseAdapter.
Should i have a database to save the selected pictures and send it to the gridview?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass the name of the image to other activity and use `getIdentifier` to get the resource id.

Comment: Thanks for replying but do you have an example with the code??

Comment: Sry for the late reply .Please check the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass name of the image to other activities rather than the view itself. Use `getIdentifier` to get the resource id and use that for setting the image.

```
 public int getResourcesFromName(Context context, String name) {
            System.out.println("getResourcesFromName: " + name);
            int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
                    context.getPackageName());
            if resourceId < 1) {
                resourceId = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            }
            return resourceId;
        }
```

Call

`imageView.setImageResource(getResourcesFromName(this, image_name));`

to set image in imageView .Also please make sure you have an image in drawable with the same name as the image_name you are passing.

Comment: The problem is that the image is set as a background for a radio button so upon clicking on a save floating button, i want to get the backgrounds of the chosen radio buttons of each row(in this case i have 8). So the image is user dependent.